# UserProfile's OneToOneField is not displayed in results

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

UserProfile model has OneToOneField connected to User model.
I would like to display detailed information from the nested field.

I used serializers to express Nested relationships. But results are same.

There is no problem to access userprofile via user instance.
for example,

```
user = User.objects.get(username="test")
user.userprofile.super_user = True
```

Could somebody help me?

*** models.py ***

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    super_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userprofile.save()
```

*** serializers.py ***

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ("phone_no", "super_user", "admin_user")


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer(read_only=True)
    # SerializerMethodField is read-only
    organization = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_organization(self, obj):
        if obj.groups is not None:
            return obj.groups.all().first().name
        return None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id",
            "profile",
            "username",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "organization",
        )
```

I would like to get an json format like below.

```
   "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "profile": {
            "phone_no": "",
            "super_user": "",
            "admin_user"
        }
        "username": "testUser",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": "",
        "organization": "testOrg"
    },
```

but the result do not display 'profile' field like below.

```
   "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "testUser",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": "",
        "organization": "testOrg"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this after changing the field name same as model name.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userprofile = UserProfileSerializer(read_only=True)
    # SerializerMethodField is read-only
    organization = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_organization(self, obj):
        if obj.groups is not None:
            return obj.groups.all().first().name
        return None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id",
            "userprofile",
            "username",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "organization",
        )
```